# Deployd Failing to Start - mongodb issue

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

Have tried to troubleshoot this issue from previous posts, but no joy so here goes.
I am working through the Apress Pro Angular book and am on a different machine today and have all the content I need to work from but Deployd is failing with the following error:

```
dpd -p 5500 sportsstore/app.dpd
Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)
bye
```

I installed Mongodb view homebrew and am just a bit unsure what I need to do. The deployd docs aren't helping.

I am running this on OSX Yosemite and Mongodb was installed via homebrew.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share you environment details ?

Comment: Crikey, apologies - will edit.

Comment: Please follow this doc http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: I have already installed Mongodb via the homebrew option.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem today, try to open command prompt in Administrator mode. Its working for me like this.